# Typing Text into DataGridTextColumn doesn´t work

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

.. but pasting text does.

What could be the reason?

```
        <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="false" Name="dataGrid" InitializingNewItem="dataGrid_InitializingNewItem" ItemsSource="{Binding SchadwagenVorgänge}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Bezeichnung" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Description}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Sortierposition" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding SortOrder}"  />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Umstellung" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ChangeOver }"   />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: On the side: avoid using special characters to name your properties/classes/fields ... (i am talking about the ä)

Comment: i´m german. i want the ä ;-)

Comment: The compiler isn't German tho xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
       <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="false" Name="dataGrid" 
       InitializingNewItem="dataGrid_InitializingNewItem" ItemsSource=" {Binding SchadwagenVorgänge}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False"  Header="Bezeichnung" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Description}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False"  Header="Sortierposition" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding SortOrder}"  />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Umstellung" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ChangeOver }"   />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: i had very strange behaviour. I had the problam only in debug-Mode. when i executed the .exe, it worked without any code changes